# If-Condition for double

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    double server = 2.11;
    double client = 2.8;

    if (server > client) {
        System.out.println("Upgrade");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Upgrade");
    }
}
```

But it returns:

```
Not Upgrade
```

I don't know what's happening with If Conditions and double data type. Anyone?

Comment: If you want to test version numbers you shouldn't be using doubles...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about misunderstanding that 2.11 is greater than 2.8

Comment: +1? Guys.. seriously..

Comment: Question should be closed, I hope

Comment: It's true that the mistake is silly, but the point about not storing version numbers as doubles is valid (although, granted, this question doesn't directly ask that).

Comment: @Jason Totally correct, I should have just gone to bed instead.

Answer (score 7):

Last time I checked, 2.11 was less than 2.8.

Consider representing version 2.8 as `2.08`, or perhaps (better) using an integer, e.g.:

```
int version = (major << 8) | minor;
```

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran That's what he should be getting..

Comment: Last time I checked, 2.11 was less than 2.8.:D

Comment: Ooops, I was thinking about 2.08, Sorry guys

Answer (score 3):

Oops sorry, I got it now

just like in the comments 2.8 is 2.80 > 2.11

Comment: What? Is this an answer?

Comment: @devnull He's a self learner :D

Comment: It's always good to answer one's own question, in case somebody else is ever wondering if 2.8 is larger than 2.11 and finds this post in the future.

Comment: @JasonC But someone might still wonder if 3.3 is larger than 3.42

Comment: @devnull Please stay on topic. That's at least 0.5 to 1.31 off topic.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yes.  I hope that we don't have too many of _such_ self-learners :)

Comment: @JasonC devnull is right.. This question is off-topic.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Sorry my joke was too subtle. I suck at jokes.

Comment: @JasonC I wrote the comment before you added the last part, now it's actually good ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Shall I nominate to reopen this and add a bounty perhaps.  This question has not received enough attention.